# Presenting an HTML Document within another HTML Document

Tags: internet, html, wiki

I am trying to embed an HTML Document that is on my local drive onto a wiki that supports HTML text. The wiki is on a closed network that also includes my computer.

As someone who is not well-versed in HTML of any sort, I have been relying on Internet searches to pinpoint exactly what I need to do. I found that I was able to use the IFRAME command to embed a published webpage into my wiki's sandbox, but I was not able to do the same for my private HTML Document.

Likewise, I have attempted SSI (Server Side Include), but nothing is returning despite laying out the file directory as such:

```
<!--#include virtual="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Prep\View\cake.shtml" -->
```

And posting this block into the sandbox.

I'm not sure if this is a silly question, but I am my own share of confused. Is there an easy solution that anyone can propose?

EDIT: In case it matters, I should add that the document whose name I masqueraded as "cake.shtml" is supported by a series of Jscript, Cascading Stylesheet, and PNG files nested up to four or five times deeper than the SHTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you could try using iframes & see if they work.

```
<iframe src="C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Prep\View\cake.shtml" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300px">
Sorry, but your browser does not support iframes.
</iframe>
```

I am not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: As a note, [iframes should be used in moderation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice)